# Spivak calculus chapter 5 limits Problem 17 a)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Prove that:
$$\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
does not exist.

I understand why it does not exist, just want  see an rigorous epsilon delta proof. Please help, I just want to know how to manipulate to get to the answer.

Comment: Can you please do rigorous proof, by assuming that the limit is L.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sufficient to show that the right-handed limit does not exist. We have that $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\frac{1}{x}\to\infty\iff\forall M>0\,\exists\delta>0:0<x<\delta\implies\frac{1}{x}>M$. Now let $\delta=\frac{1}{M}$. Can you continue?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another proof:  Suppose $\lim_{x \to 0^+} (1/x) = L$.  Clearly $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^+} 1 = 1$.  Therefore
$$
1 = \lim_{x \to 0^+} 1 = \lim_{x \to 0^+}\left(\frac{1}{x} \cdot x\right) = L \cdot 0 = 0,
$$
which is a contradiction.

This proof avoids the use of epsilons and deltas.  But of course it relies on some other facts about limits, such as the fact that a limit of a product of two functions is the product of their limits.  That fact is proven by Spivak, using epsilons and deltas.